# Problem in TrayIcon Java

Tags: java

Hi I am developing a desktop application. I used TrayIcon to set the icon in tray. But icon is not being set. I even changed the size of image-icon to 16x16. But still not displayed. If anybody could help?

Comment: not if you're not helping us to help you.
you could, for example, provide the piece of code you are using

Comment: @Tedil - he more harsh. i.e. "give code!"

Answer (score 0):

[See here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0612.html) on an example on how to do it.  A 16X16 jpg should work fine.
Maybe if you posted some code it would be easier to help you ?